# dashboard development in mvc3 with widgets

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, dashboard

I want to develope the dashboard in mvc3 for administrator where he should able top perform several operations. means with each widget there may be multiple buttons where each button wiil have the ajax call to the same action in controller. so like the update panel, i want to render only that partial part of page. I know i should use partial view.
Any guidelines for the proper approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your controller action to just return a partial view:

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartial()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

Then just call the action via jQuery and replace the HTML for the specific panel with the response data. ie:

```
$.get('/controller/action', function(data) {
    $('.myPanel').html(data);
});
```